# Delete row and reference using detached objects with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've got an object A with a @onetoone to object B, so object A contains a reference to the id of object B and I want to delete object B in the database including the reference on object A. I wonder whats the most proper solution to do this. I've hoped to set property b on object A to null, my objects are detached on the moment that I want to perform the deletion. I've tried several solutions and I've seen a wide range of exceptions to :-p

Comment: Can you please specify what have you tried? If your objects are detached I supposed you are using a query for deleting those Entities.

Comment: I'm not using a query, should I? I was hoping I could just do something like Eric's answer using the objects?

Comment: You said the entities are detached. As you wrote in a comment of Eric answer, there is no way to modify them without attach them first. You can do it with a query and it is faster (in terms of performance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
ojbecttA.setB(null);
session.update(objectA);
session.delete(objectB);
```

The most proper way, in my view, is to first

1. disassociate the two entities by setting the property to null,
2. then delete the entity you want to delete.

Comment: I've found a working "solution" by retrieving object A and B using their id's and then doing it like you said. Still, 5 lines of code to perform a simple task can't be the best solution I guess...

Comment: There should be a way of attaching and updating in one call, I thought you could do it with update(), but perhaps merge() would do it.  Fundamentally, as Mr Nobody said, you do need to attach the instances before updating.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from Hibernate-based solutions, you can instruct your databse to do it automatically by declaring your foreign key as `ON DELETE SET NULL`.